# SQL setting a Date Stamp

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm in phpmyadmin right now and I am trying to set a field to stamp the current date when data is inserted.

Now I tried setting it to `DATETIME` type, but that includes time. I just want date. I also tried setting it to `DATETIME` with the default value to `GETDATE()` and saving but it threw an error:

```
#1067 - Invalid default value for 'upload_date'
```

Anyone know how to do this please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't set the `DEFAULT` value to a function, it needs to be a constant value. One *exception* is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, although it will also include the `time` part:

```
column_name TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

However, you can use a `TRIGGER` to set the column's default value. For example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE INSERT ON your_table
  FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.date_column = DATE(NOW());
```

Also, use `DATE()` to truncate the `TIME` part of `NOW()`.

Comment: What is this variable `your_table_default_date_trigger `? I understand the your_table part, but its also attached to `default_date_trigger`??

Comment: @SofianeMerah: It's not a variable, it's just the name of the trigger. You can call it whatever you want, but the trigger name typically includes the name of the the table, and the type of the trigger. For example, `table_insert_trigger`.

Comment: ah thanks. I got an error and it claims I need to be a super user to perform the action. I can't believe that there isn't a date stamp field type in MYSQL. It should be universally needed.

Comment: @SofianeMerah: Oh, but there is, it's called `DATE`. I just assumed you had `DATETIME` instead. It's just that `NOW()` always returns the time part, so we need to truncate it using `DATE()`.

Answer (score 0):

A common error, I just throw the doc at you http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

> The DEFAULT value clause in a data type specification indicates a
>   default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must
>   be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. **This means,
>   for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be
>   the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE.** The exception
>   is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a
>   TIMESTAMP column. See Section 11.1.5.5, “Automatic Initialization and
>   Updating for TIMESTAMP”.

Also in the doc is the exception to use the current_timestamp - that requires your column to be a TIMESTAMP column.